# Arc Hydro giving Error HRESLT E_FAIL has been returned from call to Component?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arc-hydro

I have a problem with using Arc Hydro. I tried to follow these steps:

1. App utilities> Set target locations

   - Raster Data: `C:users\seabell\Deskop\weekdata4\`
   - Vector Data: `C:users\seabell\Deskop\weekdata4\untitled.gdb`
2. Fill sinks
3. Flow direction
4. Flow accumulation
5. Stream definition: I gave the number in area
6. Stream segmentation
7. Catchment grid deliniation
8. Catchment polygon processing

I receive an error which is:

> Error HRESLT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a om Component

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What step did you hit that -- I assume 8? As a general comment, I found it was less buggy to use ArcHydro via the toolbox than the menu bar; that may or may not get you to the next step!

Comment: See this video may help you in your problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK34C7QScRU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I have had same problem but I think I solved. I tried over and over.. 1- My dem is "geo-tiff" 2- folder location: in root, direct local disc C: or D: exaple C:\a\ 3- Folder and file names are shortly. exaple mxd name is "hydro", dem name is "DEM", not two word, short and one word, especially no gap. 4- When I describe "Set target locations for HydroConfig" raster data is ok. but, if vector data is "mdb" , It was not.
I described vector data "gdb" (File Geodatabase) good luck

Answer (score 4):

It appears that this is a fairly common error encountered when ArcHydro is run with data between the network and the local C: drive. See this site for further details:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/89781

The solution seems to be in where the data are stored.

Comment: As stated above, it could be a data storage issue. I used these tools pretty extensively at my last job, and the data storage was definitely key. I would suggest putting all of the data in a single .gdb

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I deleted all my file and I did whole process again and I got the results. But when I look my vector data, projection is undefined but when I started to delineate, projection has already defined. i don`t understand that why I need to include projection again?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: This is done using 10.6, I am not sure if it works for other version.
Open toolbox => Arc Hydro Tools Python => Terrain Preprocessing => Catchment Polygon Processing (or whatever raster to polygon you are choosing).

Answer (score 0):

I also face that problem. I did not do anything mentioned above. I just uninstal the ArcHydro tool box. Then reinstall the ArcHydro tool for ArcMap 10.7 specifically. Then every thing is running perfectly.  Try this